# I need a mapping service that will show aerial view (For internal use non public -- login required )

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql, vb.net, mapping

I need a mapping service that will show an aerial view that can be used with geocodes.  Company is willing to pay for the service.

VB.Net, ASP.Net, SQL, and Javascript are the languages that we use.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bing Maps and Google Maps both support these features. Google Maps starts from $10K per year for an Enterprise licence. Is there a reason one of those is not suitable (it's hard to believe you are not aware of them!!)

Comment: Yes - it is quite a chunk of change isn't it! Can you edit your question to show whether this is for an internal or public web-site.

Comment: For internal use non public -- login required